# java.io.IOException while trying to import from a compressed xml dump

Tags: java, exception, wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia

I'm trying to import a bzipped wiki XML dump into my local wiki database. I'm using a tool called [MWDumper](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aMWDumper) to import the enormous English Wikipedia XML dump. Everything seemed to be running smoothly (It appeared MWdumper was built successfully, etc.) until I actually tried importing. I started my server then ran the following (which seems to be the approach suggested on the MWDumper page in the link above):

```
java -jar mwdumper-1.16.jar --format=sql:1.5 enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 |
    mysql -u root -p my_wiki
```

I then got the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream is not in the BZip2 format
at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream.init(BZip2CompressorInputStream.java:255)
at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream.<init>(BZip2CompressorInputStream.java:138)
at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream.<init>(BZip2CompressorInputStream.java:111)
at org.mediawiki.dumper.Tools.openBZip2Stream(Tools.java:42)
at org.mediawiki.dumper.Tools.openInputFile(Tools.java:28)
at org.mediawiki.dumper.Dumper.main(Dumper.java:124)
```

which doesn't seem to make sense, since my file enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 appears to be in the correct bzip2 format. (I'm not sure if my Apache commons compress package was imported properly, although I'm assuming it was, since I don't think I would have this error message otherwise.)

**Edit: This issue has been resolved. I downloaded the third-party build of MWDumper on the MWDumper wiki page. Advice: don't try to build MWDumper from source -- it's missing tons of scattered source files from 2005; just use the third party mwdumper.jar.**

Comment: When you say it "appears" to be in the correct bzip2 format - are you able to extract it with `bunzip2`?

Comment: Well, I could try, although we're talking about 25+ GB uncompressed... I'll try a few alternatives before taking that route.

Comment: Well given that the error is specifically saying it's not valid bzip2, that looks like the first thing you should do. Sure, it may be big - but do you not *have* that much disk space? Alternatively, is there a "verify" mode in bunzip2?

Comment: I resolved the issue by downloading the third-party build of MWDumper, so the file was in fact a valid bzip2. (But thanks anyways +1.)

Comment: Thanks, added to https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Manual%3AMWDumper&diff=845955&oldid=740181 but it wouldn't harm if you added there what you had done exactly and how it failed. :)

Answer (score 0):

The OP's solution: This issue has been resolved. I downloaded the third-party build of MWDumper on the MWDumper wiki page. Advice: don't try to build MWDumper from source -- it's missing tons of scattered source files from 2005; just use the third party mwdumper.jar.